# Adding only time

Tags: r

How can I add the time alone without getting the dates attached. I am generating sample time from 2 variables but it raises the error while adding the time. Please help!

```
time1 <- format(seq(as.POSIXct('00:02:00', format = "%T"), 
                        as.POSIXct('00:03:00', format = "%T"), by = "sec"), "%T")

time1_1 <- sample(time1, 10000,replace = T)  

time2 <- format(seq(as.POSIXct('00:05:00', format = "%T"), 
                       as.POSIXct('00:13:00', format = "%T"), by = "sec"), "%T")

time2_2 <- sample(time2, 10000,replace = T)  

ab <- as.POSIXct(time1_1, format ="%T")  + as.POSIXct(time2_2, format ="%T")
```

Comment: You're not really generating times. You're generating datetimes and formatting them as times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(lubridate)
hms(time1_1) + hms(time2_2)
```

---

Or another option is `times` from `chron`

```
library(chron)
out <- times(time1_1) + times(time2_2)
head(time1_1)
#[1] "00:02:23" "00:02:43" "00:02:07" "00:02:43" "00:02:34" "00:02:30"

head(time2_2)
#[1] "00:06:04" "00:10:58" "00:06:10" "00:06:47" "00:12:33" "00:07:20"

head(out)
#[1] 00:08:27 00:13:41 00:08:17 00:09:30 00:15:07 00:09:50
```